# Ratchet Websocket with Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, redis

I have setup a Ratchet Server to communicate browser <-> server via a websocket.  The communication is working, however it seems the Ratchet service is using one Magento/MySQL connection because after ~8 hours (session lifetime) I get an error that MySQL has gone away.

Websocket Communication Script

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Wamp\WampServerInterface;
use Mage;
Mage::app();

class Pusher implements WampServerInterface {
/**
 * A lookup of all the topics clients have subscribed to
 */
protected $subscribedTopics = array();

protected $clients;

public function __construct() {
    $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session');
}

public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
    $this->subscribedTopics[$topic->getId()] = $topic;
}

/**
 * @param string JSON'ified string we'll receive from ZeroMQ
 */
public function onBlogEntry($entry) {
    $entryData = json_decode($entry, true);

    // If the lookup topic object isn't set there is no one to publish to
    if (!array_key_exists($entryData['category'], $this->subscribedTopics)) {
        return;
    }

    $topic = $this->subscribedTopics[$entryData['category']];

    // re-send the data to all the clients subscribed to that category
    $topic->broadcast($entryData);

}

public function onUnSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
}
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
}
public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
}
public function onCall(ConnectionInterface $conn, $id, $topic, array $params) {
    // In this application if clients send data it's because the user hacked around in console
    $conn->callError($id, $topic, 'You are not allowed to make calls')->close();
}
public function onPublish(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic, $event, array $exclude, array $eligible) {
    // In this application if clients send data it's because the user hacked around in console
    //$conn->close();

        $helper = Mage::getSingleton('namespace_module/websocket_communication');
        if (strpos($topic, 'request_data') !== false) {
            $helper->requestData($event, $topic);
        } else {
            $helper->logEntry($event);
        }


}
public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
}
}
```

My questions are:

1. Can I use the current session (admin/frontend) to make sure Ratchet gets a current connection each time it needs to "talk" to Magento? How would this work?
   (We are using Redis for session storage)
2. If not, how can I "reopen" the connection to Magento to avoid the MySQL gone away error?

I also saw this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8348/socket-server-and-mage-php-base-class-mysql-server-has-gone-away) which looks extremely similar, but could not figure out how to implement the proposed solutions.  Any tips/hints appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment the best solution I have come up with is to run a separate cron that restarts my websocket daemon every 6 hours (so it will catch it before the timeout).  If anyone has another solution I would be happy to try it!